# Cómo resolver warning en Rust #[warn(non_snake_case)]

Tags: rust

estoy comenzando a estudiar la sintaxis de Rust y luego de compilar me envía un warning [image: #[warn(non_snake_case)]] que no sé cómo solucionar.
No sé si alguien ya lo ha tenido y podría ayudarme a solucionarlo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un consejo, lee siempre atentamente lo que cargo te dice, porque suele ser bastante claro, quizás una de las mejores características de rust:

```
warning: crate `archivo1Rust` should have a snake case name
  |
  = help: convert the identifier to snake case: `archivo1_rust`
  = note: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` on by default
```

es decir:

```
warning: crate `archivo1Rust` debería tener un nombre estilo "snake case"
  |
  = ayuda: convierte el identificador a snake case: `archivo1_rust`
  = nota: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` activo por defecto
```

Es un warning por defecto del linter tal como cargo nos dice. Es lanzado cuando se detecta una variable, método, función, crate o parámetro *lifetime* cuyo nombre no es de la forma snake_case.

El estilo preferido en rust para nombrar estos identificadores es utilizar [snake_case](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (todos los caracteres en minúsculas y un guion bajo como separador de palabras).

En tu caso es el nombre de tu paquete, lo llamas `archivo1Rust`, por lo que no sigue esta convención de estilo. Tienes tres opciones:

- La fea: lo ignoras.
- La mala: le dices al linter que no se queje por el uso de nombres no snake_case. Por ejemplo, mediante el atributo `allow` del linter, puedes añadir:

  ```
  #![allow(non_snake_case)]
  ```

  al inicio de tu archivo `main.rs`. Esto hace que el linter no haga nada ante el uso de nombres no snake_case para los identificadores mencionados antes, para todos.
- La buena: sigues las [convenciones de estilo](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html), que permiten hacer el código mas legible para otros desarrolladores, facilitando la revisión y mantenimiento del mismo. En tu caso, renombra tu proyecto a algo que siga las convenciones, tal como el propio cargo te dice:

  Renombra la carpeta `archivo1Rust` por `archivo1_rust` (o lo que quieras siguiendo la convención de estilo) y luego abre `Cargo.toml` y cambia el nombre también:

  ```
  [package]
  name = "archivo1_rust"
  ```

  Tras eso el linter sera feliz.